# ARN role Authorisation Error while running AWS glue studio ETL script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

---

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o85.getDynamicFrame.
: java.sql.SQLException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.com$databricks$spark$redshift$JDBCWrapper$$executeInterruptibly(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:133)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.executeInterruptibly(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:109)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.buildScan(RedshiftRelation.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getLastRow(DataSource.scala:944)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getJdbcJobBookmark(DataSource.scala:805)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:829)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource$class.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:94)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Not authorized to get credentials of role arn:aws:iam::**********:role/glue_etl_role
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Not authorized to get credentials of role arn:aws:iam::*********:role/glue_etl_role
  code:      30000
  context:   
  query:     0
  location:  xen_aws_credentials_mgr.cpp:391
  process:   padbmaster
```

---

We running a AWS glue studio script to perform some join and rename operations. The connector and target are Redshift using AWS glue catalog.

At first the error was that the IAM was not added to redshift which we added. Post adding the IAM we got this new error which says Not authorised to get credentials.

Comment: try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html. this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue jobs need an IAM role with permission to access your data stores. Ensure that this role has permission to your Amazon S3 sources, targets, temporary directory, scripts, and any libraries used by the job.

Another IAM role is associated with the Redshift cluster (so the cluster have access to other AWS services on your behalf, for instance if your table is linked to S3 bucket you have to give it the permission **AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess**).

Ensure we don't mix both roles.